# How to static assert in a member function only if it is used?

Tags: c++, inheritance, static-assert

I have the following scheme:

```
struct Baz {};
struct Qux {};

struct Base {
  virtual ~Base() {}
  virtual void foo() = 0;
};

template<typename T> struct Identity { static bool const value = false; };
template<typename T> void bar(T) { static_assert(Identity<T>::value, "Busted!!!"); }
template<> void bar<Baz>(Baz) {}

template<typename T>
struct Derived : Base {
  T m;
  void foo() { bar(m); }
};

int main() {
  Base *b0 = new Derived<Baz>;
  b0->foo();
  Base *b1 = new Derived<Qux>;
  (void) b1;
}
```

That is, I have a pure virtual class `Base` and a template class `Derived` that inherits from `Base` and overrides the pure virtual function `foo` as required. Now, inside `foo` I call function template `bar`. `bar` has a specialization for class `Baz` but not for class `Qux`. When in `main` I'm trying to materialize an object of `Derived<Baz>` everything's OK. But when I try to materialize an object of `Derived<Qux>` compiler hits `static_assert`.

### Q:

Is there a way to transform my code in such a way that compiler will hit static assert in `Derived<Qux>` only if `Derived<Qux>::foo()` is called.

That is, materializing an object of `Derived<Qux>` will pass:

```
Base *b1 = new Derived<Qux>;
```

But when later in code the programmer tries to call:

```
b1->foo(); // compile error static assert
```

Comment: I think it is not possible because even though `foo` is not called it will be used to populate vtable anyway.

Comment: I think no. During the instantiation of `Derived<Qux>`, `foo` will be fully compiled. And the compiler can't always know if certain override will be called or not.

Comment: No. A virtual function is implicitly odr-used. So long as `foo` is virtual the template will be instantiated.

Comment: @StoryTeller This is understood I'm looking for a trick to maybe fool the compiler/language.

Comment: How can you fool it really? Imagine a black box that accepts a `Base *`. You basically want *your own* TU to fail to compile based on how that other black box TU was compiled. That's intractable.

Comment: @StoryTeller I'm looking for that shiny rose that will open my eyes in a new world :P. You're welcome to cast a thorough answer of why this is impossible though (i.e., standard justified).

Comment: I'd have loved it if you could get that rose, too, just so you know :)

Comment: Can the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) be reduced to the problem of whether a particular function will be called? This would mean that it is entirely impossible in any language equivalent to C++ to ever answer "yes". But I'm not sure about the reducability.

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi: you could perform the reduction like this: after program P call an otherwise unused function foo, iff foo is called, the program terminates.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The standard says an interesting thing at [[temp.inst]/9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp#inst-9):

> An implementation shall not implicitly instantiate a function
> template, a variable template, a member template, a non-virtual member
> function, a member class, a static data member of a class template, or
> a substatement of a constexpr if statement, unless such instantiation
> is required. It is unspecified whether or not an implementation
> implicitly instantiates a virtual member function of a class template
> if the virtual member function would not otherwise be instantiated.

The decision of instantiating a virtual function is up to the implementation, but only if it is not needed otherwise. The question we are faced with is therefore: when is the definition needed according to the standard itself?

The answer is at [[class.virtual]/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.virtual#11) and [[temp.inst]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp#inst-2):

> A virtual function declared in a class shall be defined, or declared pure in that class, or both; no diagnostic is required
>
> The implicit instantiation of a class template specialization causes the implicit instantiation of the declarations, but not of the definitions, default arguments, or noexcept-specifiers of the class member functions

So any instantiation of the class template, will instantiate a declaration of `Derived::foo`, which by a chain reaction requires a definition. So the definition *must be* instantiated too, if it is available.

The only way an implementation can exercise the leeway it is given in the first quoted paragraph, is if `Derived::foo` is pure virtual too. As an example, both [Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8affc8edb4c8ceb) and [GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef4055621c2623fc) do just that. That of course is likely to be of limited help to you.

So to make a long story short, it's a no-starter, so long as the function is virtual (and not pure virtual).

Answer (score 1):

@StoryTeller gives a detailed answer referencing the spec, etc. but I'm going to push back on your question and ask what you are really trying to do. As the question is written, it is dead obvious the answer is "no" because you are asking for a compile time error on something that is only determinable at runtime. E.g.:

```
Base *b;
if (user_input() == 42) {
     b = new Derived<Baz>();
} else {
     b = new Derived<Qux>();
}
b->foo();
```

Do you want a compiler error for this case? If so you'll need to define the conditions under which you think `Qux::foo` should be considered to be "called." At present the compiler is assuming a method defined as virtual in an instantiated class is called. Clearly you want something less conservative, but what?

If you have more specific compile time type information, it may be possible to catch the error at runtime. E.g.

```
Derived<Qux> d = new Derived<Qux>();
d->foo();
```

If `foo` is a non-virtual templated method, it is possible it could validate the base type at compile time and then dispatch to the virtual method. (It will likely require changing the signature of foo to have the type somehow.)

A far better solution would be to break different types of functionality in the interface into different classes and introduce a mechanism to get specific interfaces on a given concrete class. This can be checked at compile time if you have the concretely types class in hand and at runtime if doing a dynamic lookup of an interface.

Comment: I could achieve what I want in run-time by using [`assert()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert) in the place of the `static_assert`. Actually, this is what I'm doing right now. Continued...

Comment: Of course, but it is always good to ask how one can check at runtime rather than compile time. It is often possible to change the interface to allow doing so. Consider my answer an encouragement to think about if it is in your case.

Comment: I have a scheme where the API user specializes certain function templates (e.g., `template<> void bar<Baz>(Baz)` specializes `template<typename T> void bar(T)`). The goal is to define the behavior of different `Derived` classes and then to manipulate them in a common ground utilizing their common base class and treat them in a uniform matter. The user could only specify specializations for the functions her type supports/have meaning. But if by accident used a function that she hasn't provided a specialization the compiler would break compilation with an informative error message...

Comment: Right now I use a run-time assert but this way the user would get an error if the program calls that function. That is, if the error is not in the branch where her test cases apply, the program won't break at all and thus might break to the customer. Breaking at compile time is superior because it alerts the user in any case that she've done a mistake.